# play again function c

Tags: c, function, while-loop, do-while

I have a homework assignment that basically takes user input to create a golf game, asking how many holes to play, what par each hole is, and randomly generates what the person got on that hole, and prints it out. at the end, it asks the user to play again, enter y or Y for yes and n or N for no, etc. everything in my program works fine, except I cant quite get the play again function to work. here is my code, in particular, my main and the play again method:

```
int main() {
int holes, par, strokes, count = 1, low, high, go;
char *shotName;
go = 1;
while (go != 0) {
    count = 1;
    holes = readHoles();
    do {
        printf("\nHole number: %i\n", count);
        par = readPar(holes);
        low = 1;
        high = par + 5;
        strokes = calcStrokes(low, high);
        shotName = getName(par, strokes);
        printStatement(count, par, strokes, shotName);
        count++;
    }while (count <= holes);
    go = goAgain();
}
return 0;
```

}

```
int goAgain() {
char *temp;
printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? " );
scanf("%s", temp);
while (temp != 'y' || temp != 'Y' || temp != 'n' || temp != 'N') {
    printf("\nI am sorry that is invalid -- try again\n");
    printf("Would you like to play again(Y/N)? " );
    scanf("%c", &temp);
}
if (temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y') {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}

I guess im just confused on how to make this work using while loops or do while loops. This works, but when i run the program and get to the point where i have to input yes or no, anything i type causes the program to crash suddenly. and I dont know what to do. 
basically, i want the user to input something, and if its a yes, play the entire game again, if no, end the loop, and if its something else, give them an error and prompt them again. any help is appreciated its due tonight! :/  thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
while (temp != 'y' || temp != 'Y' || temp != 'n' || temp != 'N') {
```

temp can't be all the 4 at once so this will always evaluate to true change it to `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your scanf statements. In one, you are not passing the address of your variable.

```
bool goAgain()
{
    bool validInput = true;

    char temp;
    do
    {
        if (!validInput)
        {
            printf("\nI am sorry that is invalid -- try again");
        }

        printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? ");
        scanf("%c", &temp); // <== Make sure you pass the address of your variable

        validInput = (temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y' || temp == 'n' || temp == 'N');
    } while (!validInput);

    return (temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: thank you! with a little modifications to yours, (ie declaring temp outside the do while) it works perfectly! everythings perfect thank you

Comment: @anthony Please select this answer as the correct one if this is the one that fixed your problem.

Comment: This answer would be correct if you declared `temp` to be `char` instead of `char*` and used `%c` instead of `%s`.  As it is, the `scanf` call is still totally wrong and is scribbling over memory it's not supposed to. (Of course, it's hard to avoid doing that with `scanf` anyway...)

Comment: @jamesdlin You are correct, sir. I had re-arranged the original code without running it. That'll teach me... I've corrected my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *temp;
printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? " );
scanf("%s", temp);
```

You're asking `scanf` to read a string, and `scanf` needs an address to write the string to.  You supply it with `temp`, but `temp` isn't initialized to anything.  You need to allocate memory for `temp`.  This can naively be done via:

```
char temp[1024];
```

or

```
char *temp = malloc(1024);
```

which should fix your crash.  However, the buffer size of 1024 bytes is completely arbitrary, and you have no way of guaranteeing that the user's input will fit in that buffer.

In your particular case, you instead could read a single character instead of a string of unknown length:

```
char temp;
printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? " );
scanf("%c", &temp);
```

Note that now you need to call `scanf` with `&temp`. (If you don't understand why, see [Q12.12](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html) and [Q12.12b](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1a.html) from the comp.lang.c FAQ.) [However, beware of the newline left in the input buffer](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html) using this approach.

In general, [it's best to avoid `scanf` entirely](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). `scanf` is incredibly hard to use correctly (and worse, it's not obvious that it's hard to use).

A few other things:

- That `printf` call should be followed by `fflush(stdout)` to make sure that the prompt is visible when waiting for user input.
- You compare `temp == 'Y'` and such.  If you do intend for `temp` to be a string (`char*`) instead of a single `char`, then these comparisons need to be `temp[0] == 'Y'`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you tidy up the loops a bit. Lesson learned: for() is your friend ...

```
for (go = 1; go ;  go = goAgain() 
    holes = readHoles();
    for (count=0; count < holes; count++) {
        printf("\nHole number: %i\n", 1+count);
        /* Note: should this be: par = readpar(count+1); ?
        ** otherwise, it would be loop-invariant
        ** , and could be hoisted out of the loop.
        */
        par = readPar(holes);
        low = 1;
        high = par + 5;
        strokes = calcStrokes(low, high);
        shotName = getName(par, strokes);
        printStatement(count+1, par, strokes, shotName);
    }
}
```

You might argue that the `count+1` (twice!) is ugly. In that case you could alter the loop conditions : `for (count=1; count <= holes; count++) {`. But remember: that is non-standard idiom. Counting *normally* starts at zero.

Comment: i am supposed to do this only with do and while loops. cant use for loop sorry i shouldve specified that

Comment: It seems you were not allowed to use the homework tag either. Someone else had to do that for you.