# prompting user to play again in C

Tags: c, arrays, program-entry-point, scanf, prompt

I've already asked on here in another post, but none of the answers helped my program. I have a program that asks the user for numbers and calculates the mean, median, and mode. Then the program should prompt the user to play again, and if the user selects y or Y it should replay the game, n or N to stop, and if something else other than that, say invalid and please type y or n to bla bla you get it. here is my main, and my method goAgain() :

```
#define MAX 25
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readTotalNums();
void fillArray(int total, int nums[]);
void sortArray(int nums[], int total);
double findMean(int nums[], int total);
double findMedian(int nums[], int total);
int findMode(int nums[], int total);
void printResults(double mean, double median, double mode);
bool goAgain();

int main()  {
int nums[MAX];
int total;
double mean, median, mode;
bool b;
do {
    total = readTotalNums();
    fillArray(total, nums);
    sortArray(nums, total);
    mean = findMean(nums, total);
    median = findMedian(nums, total);
    mode = findMode(nums, total);
    printResults(mean, median, mode);
    b = goAgain();
} while (b==true);
return 0;
}
```

//other methods here

```
bool goAgain() {
char *temp;
printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? ");
scanf("%c", &temp);
while (temp != 'n' && temp != 'N' && temp != 'y' && temp != 'Y') {
    printf("\nI am sorry that is invalid -- try again");
    printf("\nWould you like to play again(Y/N)? ");
    scanf("%c", &temp);
}
if (temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

every time I play the game, and it gets to the prompt, anything I type it just does nothing, and keeps saying invalid try again, even if the input is a y or N. thanks for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate mean median mode c programming array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424154/calculate-mean-median-mode-c-programming-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [play again function c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370406/play-again-function-c)

Answer (score 4):

`char *temp;` should be `char temp;`

Answer (score 2):

Don't declare `temp` as a pointer, also you have not allocated memory for it.

Instead change your declaration to

`char temp;`

Answer (score 0):

since you already have the right answer, no need to say that again, so I'll add a small tip.

```
//this
if (temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

//is the same as this
return temp == 'y' || temp == 'Y';


//or more generally
if(condition)
    return true
else
    return false

//is just
return condition
```